# Example tags missing on all Trilogy sites (except Meta)

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stack-exchange, asking-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

> At least one tag such as (), max 5 tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah - missed that when converting our site resource strings to database settings.  This will be fixed in the next deployment (this evening).

Thanks!

UPDATE:  Deployed